# LDAP: unable to add user with a CN not consisting of givenname and surname

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am currently working on adding users to a ms active directory instance via ldap using php's `ldap_add`.
When specifying the DN, I must apparently use the format `cn=Firstname Lastname,CN=Users,....`. If I specify something else in the cn field (a custom username separate from the user's givenname and surname attributes, e.g. `CN=user12324`), I get the exception `ldap_add(): Add: Invalid DN syntax`. Where is this restriction specified - in the target ldap directory? in php's ldap settings?

**update:**
Running the same ldap_add query on the AD host with `ldap.exe` I am able to use a cn different from givenname + sn. So the restriction is probably somewhere in php's or the hosting server's configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was an error at the client side. When I was using php's `ldap_add` I only had CN specified in my DN (1st argument of `ldap_add`). What made the operation work was adding a separate cn in the `$entry` array (2nd argument of `ldap_add`) too.